# SpringBootTests failed due to ClassNotFoundException ObservationThreadLocalAccessor

Tags: java, junit5, spring-boot-test, spring-micrometer

I'm not sure what is the root cause, but I suspect some incompatibility might take a place here.

Here is my gradle.kts:

```
import Build_gradle.Constants.junit5Version
import Build_gradle.Constants.logbackVersion
import Build_gradle.Constants.lombokVersion
import Build_gradle.Constants.restAssuredVersion
import Build_gradle.Constants.slf4jVersion

object Constants {
    const val lombokVersion = "1.18.28"
    const val restAssuredVersion = "5.3.1"
    const val slf4jVersion = "2.0.7"
    const val logbackVersion = "1.4.8"
    const val junit5Version = "5.9.3"
}

plugins {
    id("java")
    kotlin("plugin.lombok") version "1.8.10"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.1"
    id ("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.1"
}

group = "org.home"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junit5Version}")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junit5Version}") {
        exclude("org.junit.jupiter", "junit-jupiter-api")
    }


    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:${logbackVersion}")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.2")

    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:${lombokVersion}")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")

    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured:${restAssuredVersion}") {
        exclude("commons-codec", "commons-codec")
        exclude("io.rest-assured", "rest-assured-common")
        exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging")
    }

    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:rest-assured-all:${restAssuredVersion}") {
        exclude("commons-codec", "commons-codec")
        exclude("org.apache.groovy", "groovy-xml")
    }

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude("org.junit.jupiter","junit-jupiter")
        exclude("org.mockito","mockito-junit-jupiter")
        exclude("org.skyscreamer", "jsonassert")
        exclude("org.hamcrest", "hamcrest")
        exclude("org.mockito", "mockito-core")
    }
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform() {}
}
```

Stack trace:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-17\bin\java.exe" -Dspring.profiles.active=test -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56118:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\bin"...
21:42:49.029 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [org.home.tests.api.functional.NodeCreateTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
21:42:49.049 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using ContextCustomizers for test class [NodeCreateTests]: [DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer, PropertyMappingContextCustomizer, Customizer, ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer, DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer, MockitoContextCustomizer, TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer]
21:42:49.143 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.u.TestContextSpringFactoriesUtils - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom TestExecutionListener classes or make the default TestExecutionListener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [jakarta/servlet/ServletContext]
21:42:49.147 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.u.TestContextSpringFactoriesUtils - Could not load TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.observation.MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom TestExecutionListener classes or make the default TestExecutionListener classes available.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:382)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.test.context.util.TestContextSpringFactoriesUtils.loadFactoryImplementations(TestContextSpringFactoriesUtils.java:71)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.getDefaultTestExecutionListeners(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getDefaultTestExecutionListeners(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.getTestExecutionListeners(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:89)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:294)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$before$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:203)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener requires micrometer-observation 1.10.8 or higher
    at org.springframework.test.context.observation.MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener.<clinit>(MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener.java:80)
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micrometer.observation.contextpropagation.ObservationThreadLocalAccessor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.springframework.test.context.observation.MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener.<clinit>(MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener.java:76)
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

------------------------------------ **RESOLVED** ------------------------------------

downgrading spring boot version resolved the issue    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.4"

Answer (score 0):

That is not a test failure.

Rather, it is a `DEBUG` log message pointing out that `MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener` could not be loaded due to missing *optional* dependencies.

You can safely ignore that if you are not actively using Micrometer's `ObservationRegistry` support in your tests or your test's `ApplicationContext`.

Furthermore, the support for `MicrometerObservationRegistryTestExecutionListener` has been improved in Spring Framework 6.0.11. See the following issues for details.

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30726
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30747